# Breaking loop when user clicks on a new tab - jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, tabs

I am working on some tabbed navigation for my website and I have an issue I'd like to fix.

I've been scrambling my head all day and getting nowhere. Would really appreciate some help.

Here be the code: http://jsfiddle.net/EghAt/

1) Notice when you click **Tab 1** and then immediately click **Tab 2**, **Tab 1** continues to loop out all the results.
I would prefer if this stopped looping **Tab 1** results and just started looping **Tab 2** results.

Is this possible?

How do I achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the previous animation in this function of yours, by adding the `.stop(true, true)` you see in this revised function:

```
function fadeOutItems(ele, delay) {
    var $$ = $(ele), $n = $$.next();

    // Toggle the active class
    $$.toggleClass('active');

    // Ensure the next element exists and has the correct nodeType
    // of an unordered list aka "UL"
    if ($n.length && $n[0].nodeName === 'UL') {
        $('li', $n).each(function(i) {
            // Determine whether to use a fade effect or a very quick
            // sliding effect
            delay ? $(this).stop(true, true).delay(i * 400).fadeToggle('slow') : $(this).stop(true, true).slideToggle('fast');
        });
    }
}
```

Since you call this on both the currently active tab and the newly active tab, this should stop any animations underway on the currently active tab.

See the jQuery doc on [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) for details.

In looking at this code further, I believe it does what you literally asked for in your question (it stops the previous tab looping and starts the next tab), but I'm not sure that's actually what you want because it leaves the items in a tab only partially expanded.  If that's what you want, then this will do that.

If that's not what you want, then the code will have to be modified a bit further to not only stop the currently running animations, but to put all the items for the old tab into the same state.

As I suspected, you actually want more than you asked for (per your most recent comments).  You want the previously items to be hidden, no matter what state they were in previously.  You can do that with this code where I changed the `slideToggle()` to a `slideUp()`.  You can't use any form of toggle if the animation hasn't started yet because toggle will go the wrong way (it just reverses the state).  Instead, when hiding you have to use a definitive animation that ends with the item not visible.  You can use this code where I used `slideUp()` but you could pick something different if you wanted:

```
// A helper function that allows multiple LI elements to be either
// faded in or out or slide toggled up and down
function fadeOutItems(ele, show) {
    var $$ = $(ele), $n = $$.next();

    // Toggle the active class
    $$.toggleClass('active');

    // Ensure the next element exists and has the correct nodeType
    // of an unordered list aka "UL"
    if ($n.length && $n[0].nodeName === 'UL') {
        $('li', $n).each(function(i) {
            // Determine whether to use a fade effect or a very quick
            // sliding effect
            show ? $(this).stop(true, true).delay(i * 400).fadeToggle('slow') : $(this).stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
        });
    }
}
```

You can see that in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rzd3N/.

Comment: Many thanks, jfriend00. I'm not in a position to test right now but will do as soon as possible and report back. Thanks so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: Hi jfriend00. It's not quite 100% what I need. If I click Tab 1 and click Tab 2 afterwards, it just fully loads all Tab 1 contents and then loads Tab 2. I'd like to fully close Tab 1 contents and load Tab 2.

Comment: To re-iterate it does stop the animation, but keeps Tab1 open and not closed. Any ideas how to close it when Tab 2 is clicked?

Comment: Ahhh a new requirement (not something you originally asked for), rather than just stop the current animations, you want to hide the previously active items (which makes logical sense).  I've added a revision to the end of my answer that shows you that.

Comment: Many thanks. Sorry for the delay in reply. It's been one of those weeks. I will try this right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here.

```
$(this).delay(i * 400).fadeToggle('slow')
```

You are giving a fede effect to each element at once, by increasing delay.

It's not easy to stop it this way. The correct way to do this is to call a function which will only fade an element at a time. Then this function will be executed again at a given time interval (400 in your case), and fade the next element.

This way, passing a variable to the function, for example `stopExecuting=true`, will stop the effects.

Take a look at `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you, Jose. I hope to take a look over this shortly.